# parse EMV application interchange profile for CVM list

Tags: smartcard, apdu, emv

I am trying to retrieve the CVM list from a EMV card. I have done the followings:

- Selected AID
- Get processing options

I have recieved the following response

```
77 0E 82 02 39 00 94 08 18 01 02 01 20 02 03 00 90 00
```

I have parsed this reponse with in the following website and this is the parsed info:

```
82 Application Interchange Profile 
3900
94 Application File Locator (AFL)
1801020120020300
```

https://www.emvlab.org/tlvutils/?data=77+0E+82+02+39+00+94+08+18+01+02+01+20+02+03+00+90+00+

Now what's the next step to successfully retrieve the CVM lists ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Application File locator must be explored deeper. For sample using EMV TLV parsing tool: https://iso8583.info/lib/EMV/TLVs

```
---
# Cheef's parser.
# Copyright (C) 2008-2017 Alexander Shevelev. https://iso8583.info/
# lib   : "/lib/EMV/" - Integrated Circuit Card Specifications for Payment Systems
# tool  : "TLVs"
# stat  : 25 nodes, 0 lookup tables

TLVs:#"770E8202390094081801020120020300" # EMV, Tag + Length + Value (TLV) series
- x77:#"770E8202390094081801020120020300" # EMV, Template, Response Message Format 2
  - tag: "77"
  - len: "0E" #  // 14
  - val:#"8202390094081801020120020300" # Template, Response Message Format 2.
    - x82:#"82023900" # EMV, Application Interchange Profile (AIP)
      - tag: "82"
      - len: "02" #  // 2
      - val:#"3900" # Application Interchange Profile (AIP).
        - B01: "39"
          # __1_____ - bit 6, DDA supported
          # ___1____ - bit 5, Cardholder verification is supported
          # ____1___ - bit 4, Terminal Risk Management is to be performed
          # _______1 - bit 1, CDA supported
        - B02: "00" # RFU
    - x94:#"94081801020120020300" # EMV, Application File Locator (AFL)
      - tag: "94"
      - len: "08" #  // 8
      - val:#"1801020120020300" # Application File Locator (AFL).
        - S1:#"18010201" # AFL Record
          - B01: "18" # SFI [xxxxx___] // 3
          - B02: "01" # From record // 1
          - B03: "02" # To record // 2
          - B04: "01" # First hashed // 1
        - S2:#"20020300" # AFL Record
          - B01: "20" # SFI [xxxxx___] // 4
          - B02: "02" # From record // 2
          - B03: "03" # To record // 3
          - B04: "00" # First hashed
```

Then you can READ RECORD(s) according to AFL Record definitions.
For Sample ISO 7816-4 APDU command to READ RECORD from SFI 3 Record 01:

```
rq:#"00B2011C00" # ISO 7816-3, Case 2
- CLA: "00" # Class.
- INS: "B2" # Instruction. // ISO 7816-4, Read Record
- P1: "01" # Record number or record identifier
- P2:#"1C" # Parameter 2.
  - SFI: "18" # bits 8 to 4, SFI [xxxxx___] // 3
  - ReadRecordNum: "04" # bits 3 to 1, Read Record number from P1 [_____100] // true
- Le: "00" # Length of Expected Data.
```

**Q: Now what's the next step to successfully retrieve the CVM lists ?**

**A: Read EMV Records from SFI(s) and parse TLV data response(s).**

EMV Tag 0x8E Cardholder Verification Method (CVM) List can be a part of Record.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, can you please also see this related post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47000091/parse-cv-rule-from-cvm-list-for-emv

Answer (score 1):

Application File  Locator tells where the data records are saved on the card. See how to do READ RECORD using the AFL you received. One of the READ RECORD data will contain CVM List.

Read EMV Book 3, Section 10.2 Read Application Data , and then
6.5.11 READ RECORD Command-Response APDUs

Download Books 1-4 from EMVCo [here](https://www.emvco.com/document-search/?action=search_documents&publish_date=&emvco_document_version=&emvco_document_book=&px_search=&emvco_document_technology%5B%5D=contact&emvco_document_specifications%5B%5D=specifications)

After all these if you still have trouble READing using AFL, come back here.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, can you please also see this related post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47000091/parse-cv-rule-from-cvm-list-for-emv