# Parse CV Rule from CVM List for EMV

Tags: smartcard, apdu, smartcard-reader, emv

I have succesfully retrieved the CVM List from EMV card.

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 4103 4203 1E03 1F02
```

From the EMV specification book 3, the first 4 bytes and second 4 bytes are amount and rest is CV rules. Making these the CV Rule `4103 4203 1E03 1F02`

The book also shows how to parse the CV rules, as shown below:
[image]

I am assuming that I need to convert the first two bytes in a CV rule to binary and match with the table above? But why does the table above have empty cells?
Also can someone explain in a simple pseudo code algorithm to parse this?

Comment: what is the command to retrieve cvm list? please help..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you referred section **10.5.5 CVM Processing Logic** in the same book ? It has it detailed and even as a flow cart.

As to the empty bits read as RFU.

This is how your sample is parsed.

```
41 03

41 => 0100 0001
Apply succeeding CV Rule if this CVM is unsuccessful
Plaintext PIN verification performed by ICC

03
If terminal supports the CVM
---------------------------------------------------

Similarly, 
42 03

42
Apply succeeding CV Rule if thisCVM is unsuccessful
Enciphered PIN verified online

03
If terminal supports the CVM
----------------------------------------------------

1E03

1E
Signature (paper)

03
If terminal supports the CVM

----------------------------------------------------

1F 02

1F
No CVM required

02
If not unattended cash and not manual cash and not purchase
with cashback
```

Comment: yes, I have read that section. I understand the flow and now I need to parse the CV rule. For e.g CV rule "4103", I know "03" = "If terminal supports the CVM" which clearly states in table 40. But how do I parse "41" from above table?

Comment: I have updated my original answer, it should now be clear for you

Answer (score 0):

**Q: (DO) I need to convert the first two bytes in a CV rule to binary and match with the table above?**

**A:** In the example tag 0x8E value you have:

- 2 amounts each 4 bytes length, 8 bytes in total.
- group of 4 Cardholder Verification (CV) Rules each 2 bytes, 8 bytes total CVM list length. Where in each 2 bytes rule:

  - Byte 1 is "Cardholder Verification Method (CVM) Code" which is binary table of in your request. Example: HEX value needs to be converted to binary format. Where HEX 0x**41** == binary b**01000001**. Then match bits to the table 39 with CVM Codes.
  - Byte 2 is "Cardholder Verification Method (CVM) Condition Code". The table with descriptions presented in EMV specification.

**Q: But why does the table above have empty cells?**

**A:** Because there are two Amounts 4 bytes each (8 HEX characters) in front of Tag value. Then exactly CVM rules list.

**Q: Also can someone explain in a simple pseudo code algorithm to parse this?**

**A:** See example of parsing CVM List tag 0x8E value.

```
---
# Cheef's parser.
# Copyright (C) 2008-2017 Alexander Shevelev. https://iso8583.info/
# lib   : "/lib/EMV/" - Integrated Circuit Card Specifications for Payment Systems
# tool  : "TV"
# stat  : 18 nodes, 4 lookup tables, 100.00% passed (4/4)

TV:#"8E0000000000000000410342031E031F02" # EMV, Cardholder Verification Method (CVM) List
- tag: "8E"
- val:#"0000000000000000410342031E031F02" # Cardholder Verification Method (CVM) List.
  - AmountX: "00000000" # Amount X
  - AmountY: "00000000" # Amount Y
  - CVRs:#"34313033343230333145303331463032" # CVM List
    - S1:#"4103" # Cardholder Verification Rule
      - CVMCode: "41" # Cardholder Verification Method (CVM) Code
        # _1______ - Apply succeeding CVR if CVM fails
        # __000001 - ICC Plain PIN verification
      - CVMCondition: "03" # Cardholder Verification Method (CVM) Condition Code // If terminal supports the CVM
    - S2:#"4203" # Cardholder Verification Rule
      - CVMCode: "42" # Cardholder Verification Method (CVM) Code
        # _1______ - Apply succeeding CVR if CVM fails
        # __000010 - Online Enciphered PIN verification
      - CVMCondition: "03" # Cardholder Verification Method (CVM) Condition Code // If terminal supports the CVM
    - S3:#"1E03" # Cardholder Verification Rule
      - CVMCode: "1E" # Cardholder Verification Method (CVM) Code
        # _0______ - Fail cardholder verification if CVM is unsuccessful
        # __011110 - Signature (paper)
      - CVMCondition: "03" # Cardholder Verification Method (CVM) Condition Code // If terminal supports the CVM
    - S4:#"1F02" # Cardholder Verification Rule
      - CVMCode: "1F" # Cardholder Verification Method (CVM) Code
        # _0______ - Fail cardholder verification if CVM is unsuccessful
        # __011111 - No CVM required
      - CVMCondition: "02" # Cardholder Verification Method (CVM) Condition Code // If not cash or cashback
```